# Trying to get set up with Visual Studio and git

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, github, putty

I'm struggling through getting everything set up here, I have my extension installed in visual studio 2010, and everything seems to be set up except it fails when I try and commit changes.  I'm using github and it fails on the push because it's saying I don't have the private key installed.  Where do I get this private key from for putty?

Specifically it asks for a ppk file, this was never generated that I can see.  I tried copying and pasting the private key generated into a file and gave it a ppk extension and it said it couldn't load the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the ppk key from [Puttygen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Comment: Does that key have to correspond with the key in github in any way?  I'm not really seeing the connection between the two keys.

Comment: Yes, they are a key pair.  When you generated the one for github (public), you should also have received a private key too.

Comment: It did generate a id_rsa file with a key inside, so I tried creating a text file and naming it key.ppk and pasting that key into it.  When I tried that putty gave an error saying it couldn't load the key.

Comment: How did you generate it? If it wasn't puttygen, you need to import it into puttygen and convert it to a .ppk.

Comment: Ah, ok.  No I generated it by following the tutorial on github.  It doesn't have any info about setting up putty and visual studio.

Comment: Importing it into puttygen and converting it worked. Thank you.